# data.frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe, xlsx

I am a beginner in R, and I want to create an xlsx file from R. My data frame is defined as:

```
SP : List of 8
 $ WL          : num [1:1201] 200 200 201 202 202 ...
 $ t           : num [1:872, 1] 0.499 0.999 1.499 1.999 2.499 ...
 $ SP          : int [1:872, 1:1201, 1] 380 405 447 431 419 436 439 434 422 447 ...
 $ TF          : int [1:872, 1] 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ...
 $ SpectraCount: num 872
 $ TStamp      : chr "12/01/2011 03:09:32PM"
 $ IT          : int 100
 $ SourceCount : num 1
```

I want to transform the `data.frame` into a table with one column for each value of `WL`, and one row for each value of `t`, with the values inside the table as the SP for that combination of `WL` and `t`. The resulting table would look like:

```
               WL 1,.......... 1201
            t
            1         (SP values)
            .
            827
```

---

If i put

```
write.csv(SP1, file="SP1.csv", row.names = FALSE)
```

then i have Error in  data.frame(WL = c(200, 200.5, 201, 201.5, 202, 202.5, 203, 203.5,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 1201, 872, 1

Comment: You need to "flatten" your list first.  Please see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13545547/how-to-write-a-data-frame-with-one-column-a-list-to-a-file/13555995#13555995

Answer (score 1):

Maybe generating a csv file would be enough. Excel can read csv files. See [`write.csv`](http://help.r-enthusiasts.com/library/utils/html/write.table.html) for this.

Otherwise, there is [`write.xls`](http://help.r-enthusiasts.com/library/dataframes2xls/html/write.xls.html) from the `dataframes2xls` package, or [`write.xlsx`](http://help.r-enthusiasts.com/library/xlsx/html/write.xlsx.html) from the `xlsx` package.

Comment: I'm not sure if `write.csv` writes in xls format. And do you know if `data.frame2xls` also writes in `xlsx` format? There's a `xlsx` package available. I'm guessing that may very well be what the OP is after.

Comment: Thanks. I added a mention to `xlsx`. csv is sometimes good enough. Excel reads them.

Comment: My problem is how to define, the data frame, I putted this WL <-factor(c(1:1201))
> t <-factor(c(1:827))
> SP <-c([1:872, 1:1201, 1])
then i had this error message

Comment: M <-data.frame(WL, t, SP)  the number of rows is different

Answer (score 1):

No Excel interface I know of can deal with ragged lists - you will need to convert that to a rectangular data structure.

You could of course loop over the columns of your list and write those, but I think you'd be better off just padding your list into a data.frame:

```
> l <- list(a="foo", b=c(1,2,3), d=(1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0))
> rows <- max(unlist(lapply(l, length)))
> padded <- lapply(l, function(col) c(col, rep(NA, rows-length(col))))
> as.data.frame(padded)
     a  b d
1  foo  1 1
2 <NA>  2 2
3 <NA>  3 3
4 <NA> NA 4
```

Then, you can use any of the Excel packages, with my favourite [XLConnect](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/XLConnect/index.html):

```
> library(XLConnect)
> writeWorksheetToFile(file="out.xlsx", data=as.data.frame(padded), sheet="Output")
```