# How can I convert a list having variable columns to a dataframe in R

Tags: r

A similar question has been asked before, but this is different.
I have a list of lists having each having variable number of strings in R.

Now, I want to convert this list to a dataframe. Post that, I want to remove those rows which contains strings having all 0's as well as I want to remove those strings in a row and replace it by NA which has all 0's.

For example, the list is

```
"110" "111"  
"000" "111" "101"
"0101" "1010" "1111"
"0000"
```

Now, this will be converted to a dataframe as follows.

```
"110"  "111"    NA
"000"  "111"   "101"
"0101" "1010"  "1111"
"0000"   NA      NA
```

After this I will be adding two columns to this dataframe which I can do easily. And post that, I want to remove rows which has all 0's such as row number 4 and in row number 2, I will remove the first entry.

The final result will be,

```
1 2 "110"  "111"   NA
2 3  NA    "111"  "101"
3 4 "0101" "1010" "1111"
```

How can I do it in R?

I know how to convert a list to a dataframe but not with one that has variable number of columns. Thanks!

Comment: Is it possible for you to write it in a seperate answer? And elaborate a little bit? Thanks a lot for the help. :)

Comment: and `test <- \`length<-\`(test, 3)` is equivalent to `length(test) <- 3`, fyi

Comment: @RichardScriven, that is why I wrote on top that this question might have been asked before. But my question is different. In there, it is a list in which all 0's are being removed, here, firstly, I am converting to a dataframe and then adding columns and then removing the columns having 0's. These two are different.

Comment: @RicharScriven, can you please undo your answer that you posted earlier. I will work on that. Please. :)

Comment: Yes, I would want NA in place of those strings which are all 0's. Post that, if a row then contains all NA's, I want to remove that row itself.

Comment: is this for some sort of class assignment or other data that you inherited? In general, these are "strange" R questions and possibly indicative of something gone askew further upstream...these sorts of shenanigans are not generally part of a standard workflow.

Comment: have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/13555995/1492421

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like the function `rbind.fill.matrix` from the `plyr` package may help solve your problem:

```r
library(plyr)
dat <- list(c("110","111"), 
            c("000", "111", "101"),
            c("0101", "1010", "1111"), 
            c("0000"))
dat
# [[1]]
# [1] "110" "111"
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "000" "111" "101"
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] "0101" "1010" "1111"
# 
# [[4]]
# [1] "0000"
dat <- lapply(dat, matrix, nrow=1) # convert each string to matrix
dat <- do.call(rbind.fill.matrix, dat) # bind matrices
dat
#       1      2      3     
# [1,] "110"  "111"  NA    
# [2,] "000"  "111"  "101" 
# [3,] "0101" "1010" "1111"
# [4,] "0000" NA     NA    
dat[as.numeric(dat) == 0] <- NA # replace 0's with NA 
dat <- dat[rowSums(!is.na(dat)) > 0,] # discard rows with all 0's
dat <- cbind(c(1,2,3), c(2,3,4), dat) # add two columns
dat <- data.frame(dat) # convert to data.frame
dat
# V1 V2   X1   X2   X3
# 1  1  2  110  111 <NA>
# 2  2  3 <NA>  111  101
# 3  3  4 0101 1010 1111
```

Comment: +1 for `rbind.fill.matrix`, though I think the OP is looking for something like `dat[as.numeric(dat) == 0] <- NA` and then `dat <- dat[rowSums(!is.na(dat)) > 0,]` after building `dat`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @josilber!. I didn't read the question close enough. I've edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: @PaulRegular, this shows an error in the very first line `dat <- lapply....`that `Error in FUN(X[[202L]], ...) : 
  'data' must be of a vector type, was 'NULL'`.

Comment: @sarah, I'm not seeing this error on my end...were you running the code above or trying to apply it to your data? What's the structure (`str(dat)`) of your file?

Comment: This error comes up, when the file has character strings, that is, "abc" "bca" instead of strings of 0's and 1's.

Comment: I'm still not able to replicate the error when I add non-numeric character strings to the mix...besides - even if the `lapply` line did work - the later step where rows that sum to 0 are discarded would end up giving a warning and discarding rows with non-numeric strings. Might be helpful if you edited your question and provide more detail on your data and how you need it processed.

Answer (score 1):

Creating your list:

```
myList <- list( a=c("110", "111"), 
            b=c("000", "111", "101"),
            d=c("0101", "1010", "1111"),
            e=c("0000"))
```

Expanding the list objects so every one has the same length:

```
m <- max(sapply(myList, length))
myList <- lapply(myList, function(x){length(x) <- m;x})
```

Creating the data.frame:

```
myDf <- as.data.frame(do.call("rbind", myList), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
myDf
    V1   V2   V3
1  110  111 <NA>
2  000  111  101
3 0101 1010 1111
4 0000 <NA> <NA>
```

Adding two more columns:

```
myDf <- cbind(x=1:4, y=2:5, myDf)
myDf
  x y   V1   V2   V3
1 1 2  110  111 <NA>
2 2 3  000  111  101
3 3 4 0101 1010 1111
4 4 5 0000 <NA> <NA>
```

Removing the rows in which at least one column contains all zeroes:

```
index <- sapply(myDf, function(x) which(as.numeric(x) == 0))
index <- Reduce(union, index)
index
myDf[-index, ]
  x y   V1   V2   V3
1 1 2  110  111 <NA>
3 3 4 0101 1010 1111
```

Comment: this is perfect other than the fact that you have removed the entire row in which atleast one column has all zeros. I want to convert that column value to NA and then remove the row if that row has all 0's and NA's.

Comment: This reduces the size of my original file as well.