# How can I divide a dataframe on the basis of values in its columns?

Tags: r

So, I have a dataframe like this,

```
1 2 110 10  NA  NA
2 3 101 100 NA  NA
3 4 10  NA  NA  NA
3 2 110 100 101 NA
.................
```

Now, I want to divide this dataframe into individual files as 110,10,101,100,10,101..
And each file contains the first two columns which are present in it. 
For example,
The file 110 will contain,

```
1 2
3 2
```

And the file, 10 will contain,

```
1 2
3 4
```

Like this, I want to divide it. I know how to divide it on the basis of only column value, but since the file contains multiple columns, I don't know how to do it?
Any help would be appreciated.

The code that I was able to make for single column is and then create text files was,

```
X <- split(myFile, myFile[, 4])  
invisible(lapply(names(X), function(y) 
  write.table(X[[y]], file = paste0(y, ".txt"))))
```

Comment: What's up with this dataset showing up multiple times? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26004712/how-can-i-convert-a-list-having-variable-columns-to-a-dataframe-in-r

Comment: I didn't know someone is already using that dataset. I have just opened SO and I did it on my own partially, but was stuck in multiple columns part.

Answer (score 1):

Make the dataset in long rather than wide form, then `split` it:

```
vals <- apply(dat[3:6], 1, function(x) x[!is.na(x)] )
df <- cbind(dat[1:2][rep(rownames(dat), sapply(vals,length)),], val=unlist(vals))
split(df, intm$val)

#$`10`
#    V1 V2 val
#1.1  1  2  10
#3    3  4  10
#
#$`100`
#    V1 V2 val
#2.1  2  3 100
#4.1  3  2 100
#
#$`101`
#    V1 V2 val
#2    2  3 101
#4.2  3  2 101
# 
#$`110`
#  V1 V2 val
#1  1  2 110
#4  3  2 110
```

Comment: What is intm$val in the last step?

Comment: I guess it will be `df$val` and also is there any way I can store them in automatic file in global enviornment or as seperate notepad files on disk?

Comment: @user3797829 Try `list2env(split(df, df$val), envir=.GlobalEnv)`

Answer (score 0):

You may do it this way:

dat is your data.frame

```
dat110 <- dat[which(dat[, 3:4] == 110, arr.ind = T)[, 1], 1:2]
```

first we look for array indices for which columns 3:4 have value 110 # which(dat[, 3:4] == 110, arr.ind = T) (here you should change 3:4 to indices of your columns)

next we selectonly row indeces # it is [, 1] following which(...)

finally we pick first 2 columns of dat but only rows selected in previous section # dat[which(...), 1:2]

You could use for loop to change condition value, i.e. 110.

My example:

```
dat <- data.frame(x=1:3,y=2:4,z=0:2,w=2:4)

for(i in unique(unlist(dat[,3:4])))
{
tmp <- dat[which(dat[, 3:4] == i, arr.ind = T)[, 1], 1:2]
print(i)
print(tmp)
}
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the input. Can you elaborate on it a little bit. And write it properly. Thanks. :)

Comment: Process dataframe in loop iterating through all distinct values of your 3:6 columns (10, 100, 101, ...), in each iteration retrieve first 2 columns that meet the condition (value of columns 3:6 equals current iteration value) and save the result to file. I've added simple example to previous post.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try:

```
 library(dplyr)
 library(tidyr)

 dat1 <- dat %>% 
             mutate(indx=row_number()) %>% 
             gather(Var, Val, V3:V6) %>%
             filter(!is.na(Val))%>%
             arrange(Val, indx) %>% 
             select(-indx, -Var)

 lst1 <- split(dat1, dat1$Val)
 lst1
 #$`10`
 #  V1 V2 Val
 #1  1  2  10
 #2  3  4  10

 #$`100`
 #  V1 V2 Val
 #3  2  3 100
 #4  3  2 100

 #$`101`
 #  V1 V2 Val
 #5  2  3 101
 #6  3  2 101

 #$`110`
 #  V1 V2 Val
 #7  1  2 110
 #8  3  2 110
```

If you need them as individual datasets in the `global environment`, one option is `list2env` or you could use `assign` (but not recommended as it will create a lot of objects in the global env).  Instead, you could do all the necessary calculation within the list itself and use `lapply` with `write.table/write.csv` to save as individual files.  But, if you need as individual datasets:

```
 list2env(setNames(lst1, paste("dat", names(lst1), sep="_")), envir=.GlobalEnv)
 <environment: R_GlobalEnv>
 dat_10
 #  V1 V2 Val
 #1  1  2  10
 #2  3  4  10
```

#### data

```
dat <- structure(list(V1 = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 3L), V2 = c(2L, 3L, 4L, 2L), 
V3 = c(110L, 101L, 10L, 110L), V4 = c(10L, 100L, NA, 100L
), V5 = c(NA, NA, NA, 101L), V6 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA)), .Names = c("V1", 
"V2", "V3", "V4", "V5", "V6"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```